# How to chain javascript date functions

Tags: javascript, date, chaining

Is there a way to chain javascript date functions?

for example, I would like to something like this:

```
var d = new Date().setMinutes(0).setSeconds(0).setMilliseconds(0);
```

this syntax breaks with error:

```
(new Date).setMinutes(0).setSeconds is not a function
```

I know I can do this:

```
var d = new Date();
d.setMinutes(0);
d.setSeconds(0);
d.setMilliseconds(0);
```

but this feels verbose and cumbersome. Is there a better way?

Comment: Yes.  http://momentjs.com/

Comment: Nice.  Thank you.  I'd seen JodaTime for Java, and assumed there was an equivalent library in Javascript.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can set seconds and msecs with the setMinutes method:

```
var d = new Date();
d.setMinutes(0,0,0);
```

Also works with hours- `d.setHours(0,0,0,0);`

Comment: I guess the answer is "no" you can't chain, but I didn't know that setHours (and apparently setFullYear) can take multiple parameters.  It is a reasonable work around for what I need.

Answer (score 5):

You can pass parameters to [Date constructor](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_date.asp). E.g.

```
var d = new Date(null, null, null, null, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: @kennebec What would you want the actual date to be ?

Comment: This would be the best answer if passing 'null' defaulted to the current year, month, date.  However, it appears this would give me December 31, 1899.  Usually I am trying to manipulate dates relative to the date the user interacts with my website.  I don't know what day it is going to be, but I want noon on that day or 5 days at noon from that day. d.setHours(16,0,0,0) to set something for that day at 4:00pm is my most common scenario.

Answer (score 1):

This question is fairly old, but you can combine Kennebec's answer with Yuriy's to make it a single line if desired:

```
var d = new Date(new Date().setMinutes(0,0,0))
```